# API Microservices bundle multiple services as one deployment Vs separate deployable for each service

Tags: api, api-design, microservices, deployment

So I am going to be developing atleast 5-6 Res end points . ( all distinct and stateless )
Now I am debating on the following:

- Should they be combined as  single war / ear or deploy each service separately ?
- deploying them as single war - down time during deployment should that be a concern ? ( with load balancer - ideally there shouldnt be any down time correct ? )
- in case of any issues in case of a single war all services would be impacted Vs a single service - how realistic is this ?
- any other parameters that should be considered ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The entire point of microservices is that they are independently deployable and scaleable. If you're talking about 5-6 literal endpoints (uri endpoints, sockets, message types - effectively 5-6 callable functions) then putting them together is fine. Having a single function per deployment is probably pathologically/impractically micro.

If you're talking about 5-6 entities (and all of the operations to work on them), it becomes a matter of tradeoffs. Are the entities likely to change together? Is your CI/CD process mature? Will your project go under if you don't ship tomorrow?

If you're talking about 5-6 concepts, each with multiple entities and all of the operations they need... then they should probably get deployed separately. I mean, you can certainly deploy them all together for ease of implementation - but they're not really microservices at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the answers that Microservices architectures raise regarding this topic are tightly related to the company's business strategy towards the market.

Microservices is not an end. It's a mean to an end.  It's the business strategy who on way or another drives the solution to implement. You have to ask first the stakeholders which behaviour is acceptable.

> Should they be combined as single war/ear or deploy each service
>   separately?

As @Telastyn answered, it depends on what those 5-6 endpoints are. Their responsibilities, their criticality.

> deploying them as single war - downtime during deployment should that
>   be a concern?

With or without balancing, it should be. If endpoints cover different business capabilities, you should ask the stakeholders what downtime is acceptable for each capability. You might find that some services (endpoints) are more critic than others. Some could remain down for longer than others without causing significant losses for the company. Imagine what would happen if Amazon took down its *Cart service* or the *payment gateways* for a couple minutes.

> in case of any issues in case of a single war all services would be
>   impacted Vs a single service - how realistic is this?

Of course, a DDoS attack would compromise all the system (if the system is comprised of those 5-6 endpoints). What lives as a whole, dies as a whole too.

> any other parameters that should be considered?

Too many to be summarised in a short and concise answer.

The unwritten rule of Microservices is **divide and conquer**. How much to divide is purely strategy.